# Не инициализируется массив в pascal

Tags: pascal

я столкнулся с такой проблемой, я создал массив с именем mas : array[0..255] of integer;
В программе мне пишет компилятор что переменная типа mas не инициализирована, 
что делать, как исправить.
Вот программа:

```
Program HM;
var k, i, n, h, l : integer;
mas : array[0..255] of integer;
s : string;
begin
 k := 0;
 i := 1;
 n := 0;
 h := 0;
 l := 0;
 writeln('Введите строку');
 readln(s);

 while (n <> 2) or (i = Length(s)) do 
 begin 
  if (ord(s[i]) - 43) <> 0 then 
  begin 
   n := 0;
   mas[k] := mas[k]*10 + ord(s[i])
  end
  else
  begin 
   n := n + 1;
   k := k + 1;
   h := h + 1;
  end;
 end;

 for i:=0 to h do
 begin 
  l := l + mas[i];
 end;
 writeln(l);
end.
```

Comment: Код, который Вы включили в вопрос, не соответствует сообщению компилятора. -1

Comment: Приведите оригинальный текст ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор говорит правду. Переменная не проинициализирована.

Вам нужно задать начальное значение каждому элементу массива

Comment: нет, что-то здесь не то.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор вам говорит правду. Вероятнее всего вы используете `free pascal`. По дефолту компилятор то создаст (выделит место в памяти), но не заполнит нулями. Вам нужно в начале программы пробежаться по каждому элементу и задать ему значение:

```
for i := 0 to Length(mas) do
begin
   mas[i] := 0;
end;
```